# How to Change Text Color on a Div Child Element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, domdocument

A section of a webpage has DIV elements that look like the following:

```
<div class="nodePedigree node male " id="0:7" style="height:0.57em; width:2.95em; left:7.076em; top:0.07959999em;" T:NodeId="0:7">
    <div class="nodeContent">
        <div class="vAlignContent">
            <h6 class="nodeTitle">John Doe</h6>
            <div class="nodeInfo">1860-1915</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nodePedigree node female " id="0:5" style="height:0.57em; width:2.95em; left:3.814em; top:4.081em;" T:NodeId="0:5">
    <div class="nodeContent">
        <div class="vAlignContent">
            <h6 class="nodeTitle">Jane Doe</h6>
            <div class="nodeInfo">1903-2000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are DIV elements placed within other DIV elements.

These are just 2 of the many DIV elements like this in the webpage. The "parent" DIV elements can be differentiated by the value of id. In this case, they are id="0:7" and id="0:5", but in other cases it could be "0:1", "0:2" ... "0:20", "0:21", etc.

In JavaScript, I am trying to find specific "parent" DIV elements and then change the background color for the associated "child" DIV element (called "nodeContent").  In other words, I don't want to change the background color for ALL "nodeContent" DIV elements, but just specific ones.  So for example, I would like to change the background color to "red" for the "nodeContent" DIV element that is a "child" of the "parent" DIV element that has id="0:5".

I know how to find the "parent" DIV with the following code:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('0:5');
```

But I don't know how to then find the associated DIV "child" element called "nodeContent" (so that I can then change the background color).

Answer (score 1):

Call `getElementsByClassName()` on the parent node, then use the first node in the list:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('0:5');
var nodes = parent.getElementsByClassName('nodeContent');

nodes[0].style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
```

```html
<div class="nodePedigree node male " id="0:7" style="height:0.57em; width:2.95em; left:7.076em; top:0.07959999em;" T:NodeId="0:7">
    <div class="nodeContent">
        <div class="vAlignContent">
            <h6 class="nodeTitle">John Doe</h6>
            <div class="nodeInfo">1860-1915</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nodePedigree node female " id="0:5" style="height:0.57em; width:2.95em; left:3.814em; top:4.081em;" T:NodeId="0:5">
    <div class="nodeContent">
        <div class="vAlignContent">
            <h6 class="nodeTitle">Jane Doe</h6>
            <div class="nodeInfo">1903-2000</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```