# Change child link color with javascript

Tags: javascript, properties, themes, anchor

I have webpage with a header and body and footer
I put a script to change the theme from dark to light when switch button is clicked.
But not all links  have the same color, for example i want those of the header to be "white" and those of body to be "silver",

So for the header i have a definition like this :

```
#header a{color:black}
#header a:hover{color:red}
```

I could change the text color as :

```
var hdr = document.getElementById("header");
hdr.style.color = "#white";
```

My question is how to change the color of child "a" of element header with javascript the same way as i am doing it with header it self ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much asked from you - you want to select `header` id, and change all the `a` tags inside it.

So, you're looking for the selector for the `a` tags inside the `header` id.

Select all the `a` anchor tags, and change all tags with loop, to your desired color.

```
let headerAnchorTags = hdr.getElementsByTagName('a'); //you have already selected hdr
        
for(var i=0; i<headerAnchorTags.length; i++){
   headerAnchorTags[i].style.color = "black";
  }
```

Comment: both solutions works the one from charlietfl and Brown Paul, i will give an accept for Paul because of two thing it easier for me and Charlietfl already is 163k reputaion he is in the government so let help the PEOPLE Thanks guys both of you

Comment: you're helping gain reputation. As about the question - the ideal way to change dark to light is to change(`toggle`) through Javascript, when you've got defined css for both light and dark themes, and with Javascript you switch that. That's the ideal way. But your question was direct how to select the anchors inside header. So, that was my solution. If you want more stable way, the below method - defining both - light and dark css themes, and toggling is ideal. But your approach was economic, and simple - so was my answer.

Comment: was just kidding about the rep, i know the best practise is to toggle class but as beginner in css and having delphi programming background, i feel cumfurtable with JS, anyway i will try both and see if i can implement toggle classe for each element of my webpage, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Toggle a class on the `<body>` and then create specific rules that use that class in them.

Something like:

```
#header a {color: black}
#header a:hover {color: red}

.dark #header a {color: white}
.dark #header a:hover {color: pink}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call the child elements by originally grabbing the 'family' with getElementsByClassName(). So instead of using an id, change it to a class and then you can grab the hierarchy that way.
Then you can use an index to select the correct child.

Here's a link that may be useful.

[How to Change Text Color on a Div Child Element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529208/how-to-change-text-color-on-a-div-child-element-in-javascript)